# Why Doesn't compareTo() work?

Tags: java, generics, arraylist, compareto

I have two ArrayLists:

```
ArrayList<String> testList = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<String> wordList = new ArrayList<>();
```

They are being passed into a method:

```
public static void binSearch(ArrayList a1, ArrayList a2)
```

Inside the method, I want to compare the strings between the two ArrayList:

```
a1.get(i).compareTo(a2.get(newEnd / 2))
```

However, I received an error message:

```
cannot find symbol
symbol: method compareTo(Object)
location: class Object
```

I heard some people say that I need to implements/extends Comparable, but it seems like some people are just doing fine with the method without importing/implementing/extending anything.

Comment: `ArrayList` (without generics) doesn't implement `Comparable` (or have a method called `compareTo(Object)`. You either need to provide a custom comparator or change your method signature to something more like `public static void binSearch(ArrayList<Comparable> a1, ArrayList<Comparable> a2)`

Comment: @abdelhak newEnd is an int that holds the index for the ArrayList because it is a method that does binary search

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do not use raw types. Declare your `binSearch` this way:

```
public static void binSearch(ArrayList<String> a1, ArrayList<String> a2)
```

Or if you want to support any `Comparable` types introduce generic type variable:

```
public static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> void binSearch(List<T> a1, List<T> a2)
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!  It is exactly what I was looking for, and it works perfectly.